# ¿Como puedo saber si un Fragment esta visible actualmente en Android Studio?

Tags: android

Hola que tal necesito de su ayuda para saber como ver si un fragment esta visible actualmente en android studio

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Bienvenido, revisa por favor [ask], edita tu pregunta y agrega más información , saludos.